# Newtonsoft.Json serializing into static readonly class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have `public class Result` and object created from it:

```
public static readonly Result NotStarted = new Result(1, "", nameof(NotStarted));
```

This is realization of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) pattern. In my case Result is based on TypesafeEnumBase:

```
public class TypesafeEnumBase : ITypesafeEnum
{
    [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "")]
    [JsonProperty("text", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public virtual string Description { get; protected set; }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(int), "1")]
    [JsonProperty("code", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "")]
    [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
}
```

Now I'm receiving json object serialized from type containing Result property

```
[DataContract, Serializable]
public class IOResultBase : IIOResult
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    [JsonProperty("Result", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }

    public IOResultBase()
    {
        this.Result = Result.NotStarted;
    }
}
```

You may notice that there is default value in constructor equals to `Result.NotStarted` static class.

I get json like this `{"Result":{"text":"","code":0,"name":"Success"}}`
As you notice it has code of 0. And now `IOResultBase foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IOResultBase>(json)` is pushing this code 0 into foo.

But it turns out that 0 is being pushed in `public static readonly Result NotStarted` itself (even despite its readonly) instead of just creating new instance of foo.Result. So now 'code' of NotStarted (which is actually globally used constant) is changed from 1 to 0.

How should I force DeserializeObject to create new instance of `public class Result` instead of overriding `public static readonly Result NotStarted`?

Comment: And where is your public class Result and interfaces IIOResult, ITypeSafeEnum and so on?

Comment: @Serge, why is that relevant with regard to the posed question? The question clearly expains what happens, it explains what the OP would like to happen instead, and asks how OP could get it to happen like they want. Which is basically: "I don't want this object in that property being changed by the deserializer, i want the deserializer to put a new object with the json data in that property"

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace According the rules of this resource  the OP should post a minimal example that could be tested. I can not do it now so how I can tell what is the problem and what can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay utmost attention to the [default (de)serialization settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm) of Newtonsoft.Json. Quite a few will not be what many would intuitvely expect them to be.

Such as, if there is an existing object instance in a property like the `Result.NotStarted` instance in the `IOResultBase.Result` property, Newtonsoft.Json will try to *reuse* the existing object instance provided by the property, meaning populating this existing instance with the values from the json.

Specifially, to solve your problem, you will have to set Newtonsoft.Json's setting [`ObjectCreationHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#ObjectCreationHandling) to `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`. So, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IOResultBase>(
    json,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace }
);
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer but not quite. For tow reasons: I cannot use ITypesafeEnum interface (DeserializeObject is trying to create instance based on it, maybe there is one more option for that?) and it is not quite safe - I need to always remember to use `new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace }` in serializers. Is there the way to protect the class itself?

Comment: This is the answer to the question as you posed it. Fully. If you want/need to ask a new question then ask it as a question please, and not as a comment. Try avoiding to move the goal posts. If you forgot to ask about that in your original question, then ask it as a new question. It would be a different story if my answer would not have addressed what you asked about in your question and you alerting me to something i missed in your question, but that does not seem to be the case here...

Comment: It seems that I can use `ObjectCreationHandling` in attribure `[JsonProperty("Result", ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]` so it solves that problem. TY for help.